# Write a function rule

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Write a function rule for a number pattern that has -30 as the eighth term.**

How would you go about without knowing another number in the pattern?

Comment: $n\mapsto -30\cdot0^{|n-8|}$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the restrictive information available to you. For example, in this problem you have to create a sequence of numbers where the eighth term is $-30$. So an easy answer is to make the seventh term $-60$, then the sixth term is $-120$, etc. See where this is going?

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, was overthinking the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about 
$y=-30$ where $y$ is the output.

Or you could do something like $y=-3.75x$

There are literally infinite possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the easy way out and say all terms are $-30$.  There are infinitely many other choices which satisfy the requirement.